# Prove $f[X]\backslash f[X']\subset f[X\backslash X']$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

edit: $f[X]=\{f(x):x\in X\}$

$f[X]\backslash f[X']\subset f[X\backslash X']$

Simple: Proof by definition. What I would like to provide is a counter-example and intuition to the reverse of this question. Please correct me if I am wrong. If it is correct, I hope this could serve as a reference to the textbook which I can't find its solution in the internet.

$f[X\backslash X']\subsetneq f[X]\backslash F[X']$

Counter-example: constant mapping

1. $X\cap X'=\emptyset,A=X\cup X',B:\{y\}$
2. $f:A\rightarrow B\;s.t.f(x)=y\;\forall x\in A$
3. $f[X\backslash X']=f[X]=\{y\}=f[X']$
4. $f[X]\backslash f[X']=\{y\}\backslash \{y\}=\emptyset$
5. $\{y\}\subsetneq\;\emptyset$

Intuition:

1. $A\subset\emptyset\equiv\;False$
2. $f[X]=f[X']\rightarrow f[X]\backslash f[X']=\emptyset$
3. $X\cap X'=\emptyset\rightarrow X\backslash X'=X\;and\;X\neq\emptyset\;and\;X\neq\emptyset$
4. $f[X]\subsetneq\emptyset$

So it all depends on which is which--either you find constant mapping or manipulation on statement calculus mechanical.

Comment: What is $f[X]$?

Comment: $f(x):x\in X$ direct image of a set

Comment: So you mean $f(X)$.

Comment: No, it's a set of $f(x)$ s.t. $x\in X$

Comment: I did understand, however denoting the direct image with square brackets is unusual. You normally use round brackets. Note that you can differentiate between the direct image $f(X)$ and the point $f(x)$ by the size of the x.

Comment: I see ur confusion, haha. I took the square parentheses practice from my textbook actually lol

Comment: Right. I just haven’t seen this notation before. Normally you denote by square brackets things like polynomials or free objects, so I got confused...

Comment: However, the inclusion will be an equality if $f$ is injective.

Comment: In set-theoretical circles it is not at all unusual to use square brackets for images of sets -- on the contrary, I'd argue in this context $f(X)$ might be confusing as $X$ is not in the domain of $f$. OP's usage, in this context, is totally standard.

Comment: Hello guys, the textbook I am referencing is attached below
https://lib.hku.hk/Press/9622090133.pdf
P.64/76

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $f:\{0,1\}\rightarrow \{*\}$. Note that there is no choice to make, you have to send $0$ and $1$ to $*$. Now $f(\{0\}) = \{*\} = f(\{1\})$, hence $f(\{1\})\setminus f(\{0\}) = \emptyset$, however $f(\{1\}\setminus \{0\}) = f(\{1\}) = \{*\} \neq \emptyset$.